# How can I format e.Day.Date command of calendar show only Date?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, calendar

I want to use only Date for check my function but it always get the time follow or can I format timezone of e.Day.Date.Year to show timezone what i want ? 3
This is example of my code the first code at e.Day.Date.Year of year is "en-US"
but i want to change timezone of the value can i ?

```
g = (e.Day.Date.Day + "/"+ e.Day.Date.Month + "/" + e.Day.Date.Year)
```

and
This line value of e.Day.Date always have time follow the date with 00:00:00 it can't check with the other time

```
if(e.Day.Date == dt)
```

Comment: no code, no explanation and too narrow.

Comment: apologize about that I'm just a newbie

Comment: Your edit greatly improved your question. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Glad we could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want DateTime.Date rather than .Day

See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbed0aaa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2008, 6, 1, 7, 47, 0);
      Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString());

      // Get date-only portion of date, without its time.
      DateTime dateOnly = date1.Date;
      // Display date using short date string.
      Console.WriteLine(dateOnly.ToString("d"));
      // Display date using 24-hour clock.
      Console.WriteLine(dateOnly.ToString("g"));
      Console.WriteLine(dateOnly.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"));   
   }
}
// The example displays output like the following output:
//       6/1/2008 7:47:00 AM
//       6/1/2008
//       6/1/2008 12:00 AM
//       06/01/2008 00:00
```

Comment: In .Day is function of calendar it's auto random date/month/year to check with value but it always have time follow everytime

Comment: Did you read the code example in my link? It you want to show the date only with no time then use `e.Date.ToString("d")` or format it however you want like this `Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")` or you could swap the month around like this `Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")`

Comment: Thank you for your recommend I just finish to understand it